# GradeBook program that doesn't display the letter grades of each and every student

Tags: c++, oop, debugging

I'm doing an assignment where we have created a `Student` class and `Course` class. The program will create an array of 7 students and then will use the `CourseObj` to call methods for each for the 7 students such as:

```
    `courseObj.evaluate_class();`
```

inside the evaluate_class method will be a methods that will call some of the methods inside of the student class such as

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        student[i].compute_student_stats();
        student[i].determine_student_grade();
    }
    return;
```

This is just to give you a sense of the program

```
using namespace std;
ofstream toFile;
class Student
{
     private:
        string name;
        int project[6];
        int exam[2];
        int quiz[5];
        double project_avg;
        double exam_avg;
        double quiz_avg;
        int finalExam;
        double average;
        string grade;
     public: 
        Student();
        void get_student_scores();
        void compute_student_stats();
        void determine_student_grade();
        void display_student_name_gpa_grade();
        double student_average();
};

class Course
{
    private:
        Student student[7];
        int index_of_highest;
        int index_of_lowest;
    public:
        Course();
        ~Course();
        void get_grades();
        void evaluate_class();
        void determine_index_of_highest_lowest();
        void display_highest();
        void display_lowest();
        void display_stats();
};

Student::Student()
{
    name = " ";

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        project[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        exam[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        quiz[i] = 0;

    average, project_avg, exam_avg, quiz_avg = 0.0;
    finalExam = 0;
    grade = " ";
}

void Student::get_student_scores()
{
    //Test try catch heavily
    try
    {
        cout << "\n Enter Student Name: \n";
        cin>>name;

        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Student project grade #"<<i+1<<":\n";
            cin>>project[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Student exam grade #"<<i+1<<":\n";
            cin>>exam[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Student quiz grade #"<<i+1<<":\n";
            cin>>quiz[i];
        }

        cout << "Enter final exam grade: \n";
        cin>>finalExam;    
    }

    catch(...)
    {
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout<<"Error, invalid input entered. \n";
    }
    return;
}

void Student::compute_student_stats()
{
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        project_avg += project[i]; 
    project_avg = project_avg/6;
    cout << "Project Average = " << project_avg << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        exam_avg += exam[i]; 
    exam_avg = exam_avg/2;
    cout << "Exam average = " << exam_avg << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        quiz_avg += quiz[i]; 
    quiz_avg = quiz_avg/5;
    cout << "Quiz average = " << quiz_avg << "\n";

    average = (project_avg*0.25) + (exam_avg*0.4) + (quiz_avg*0.1) + (finalExam*0.25);
    cout << "Semester average = " << average << "\n"; 

    return;
}

void Student::determine_student_grade()
{
    if(average <= 100 && average >= 93)
    {
        grade = "A";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }

    else if(average <= 92 && average >= 89)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 88 && average >= 87)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 86 && average >= 83)
    {
        grade = "B";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 82 && average >= 79)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 78 && average >= 77)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 76 && average >= 73)
    {
        grade = "C";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 72 && average >= 69)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 68 && average >= 67)
    {
        grade = "D+";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 66 && average >= 63)
    {
        grade = "D";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 62 && average >= 57)
    {
        grade = "D-";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    else if(average <= 57)
    {
        grade = "F";
        cout << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    }
    return;
}

void Student::display_student_name_gpa_grade()
{
    const int width1 = 19;
    const int width2 = 17;

    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    cout << left << setw(width1) << "Student = " << name;
    cout << right << setw(width2) << "Average = " << average;
    cout << right << setw(width2) << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";

    toFile.open("student.txt",ios::app);
    toFile<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    toFile << left << setw(width1) << "Student = " << name;
    toFile << right << setw(width2) << "Average = " << average;
    toFile << right << setw(width2) << "Letter Grade = " << grade << "\n";
    toFile.close();
    return;
}

double Student::student_average()
{
    //remeber to round to nearest tenth in main
    return average;
}



Course::Course()
{
    index_of_highest = 0;
    index_of_highest = 0;
}
Course::~Course()
{
    cout << "Course Object is going out of existence.";
}
void Course::get_grades()
{
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
        student[i].get_student_scores();    
    return;
}

void Course::evaluate_class()
{
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        student[i].compute_student_stats();
        student[i].determine_student_grade();
    }
    return;
}

void Course::determine_index_of_highest_lowest()
{
    int tempHighest = 0; 
    int tempLowest = 100;

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if(student[i].student_average() > tempHighest)
        {
            tempHighest = student[i].student_average();
            index_of_highest = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if(student[i].student_average() < tempLowest)
        {
            tempLowest = student[i].student_average();
            index_of_lowest = i;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void Course::display_highest()
{
    student[index_of_highest].display_student_name_gpa_grade();
        return;
}

void Course::display_lowest()
{    
    student[index_of_lowest].display_student_name_gpa_grade();
        return;
}

void Course::display_stats()
{    
    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        student[i].display_student_name_gpa_grade();
    }
}

void describeProgram()
{
    cout<<"This program will serve as a grade book for seven students who are"
          " participating in a course, \n and will also analyze the performances"
          "of the students as well. Each student will have six projects (worth 25%"
          " collectively), \n two midterm exams (worth 20% each), and five quizzes (worth 10%"
          " collectively), and a final exam (worth 25%). \n The program will calculate"
          " the class average and will also display the student with the highest"
          " and lowest grade.";  
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Course courseObj;

    describeProgram();
    courseObj.get_grades();
    courseObj.evaluate_class();
    courseObj.determine_index_of_highest_lowest();

    toFile.open("student.txt",ios::out);

    toFile<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<endl;
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<endl;  

    courseObj.display_stats();
    cout << "\n";
    toFile << "\n";

    cout<<"The name, average, and grade of the best student in the class is:\n";
    toFile<<"The name, average, and grade of the best student in the class is:\n";  
    courseObj.display_highest();

    cout<<"The name, average, and grade of the poorest student in the class is:\n";
    toFile<<"The name, average, and grade of the poorest student in the class is:\n";
    courseObj.display_lowest();
    toFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

My problem currently is the fact that sometimes, the program will not display a letter grade for a student that is who's average has already been calculated. I can't seem to figure out exactly why it is that the program sometimes figures our the letter grade and sometimes doesn't.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5NUh.png) is a picture of the output of `display_student_name_gpa_grade()` when I hard-coded everything to be the same
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVv3S.png), you can see that max and kevin were the only two students that didn't have a letter grade assigned. Believe me, it is not a matter of input either. The only case I have found in which the letter grade will not show is if you misclick and type an extremely large number (above 100). Other than that, i Can't seem to find the reason as to why it will sometimes not output a `letterGrade`.

Comment: I highly recommend pasting the results (output) of your debugging session *as text* into your question.  Firewalls prevent following links.  Screen snapshots don't scale well (Think of people who use mobile phones to access this site or people with smaller monitors).

Comment: You could simplify your program by placing the grade data into a table of  `struct Grade_Info {int minimum; int maximum; std::string grade_letters;};`.  You could use a loop to search the table (vector or array).

Comment: This is still not an [mcve].  I'd like to have a program I can paste into my IDE and verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:
average, project_avg, exam_avg, quiz_avg = 0.0;
only assigns quiz_avg and none of the other variables. Use a = b = c = 0.0 form instead.

Also Student::determine_student_grade does not handle the case where average is > 100 (which you probably thought should never happens but it does). Consider using an assert for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the variables used to calculate the averages are not initialized.

Rather than

```
double project_avg;
```

use:

```
double project_avg{};
```

The latter will initialize the value to zero.